# Reply using default account regardless of source account?

Tags: 11.10, evolution, email

I have multiple accounts in Evolution 3.2, but only want to reply from one of them, regardless of which account the email came into - does anyone know if this is possible?

For example, email comes in under Account 3, but I want to reply using Account 1 *by default*  (I know you can manually select the account at the top of the email message).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!